# Resource for learning the details of Java Web Services?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I'd like to build a Java Web Service using JAX-WS and GlassFish 3. All of the guides showing the basics of Web Services in Java using tools like *wsgen* and *wsimport* to generate a lot of the boilerplate code to implement the Web Service. Is this just how it is done or does anyone know of some resources that go into more of the details?

Comment: you might consider using jax-rs instead, depending on what this is for. much less overhead for small projects, in my opinion...

Comment: I could get away with it, and might use rs instead - but I really just want to learn the basics and mechanics of web services in java

Comment: Cool. In that case, since I'm already being opinionated, I'll keep going: REST services are kind of the thing these days, and SOAP/RPC style stuff is slowly going out of fashion. Give Jersey a shot, and for reference material I recommend "RESTful Web Services Cookbook."

Comment: I strongly disagree with 'SOAP/RPC style stuff is slowly going out of fashion'. SOAP have something very important for complex integration scenarios: a contract (WSDL). For this reason people that work in big enterprises with a very complex system architecture prefer SOAP+BPEL over any other integration approach. And actually, with SOAP you can do RESTful-like services. I'm not a SOAP fan, but this is the reality. I love (and prefer) RESTful 'state of mind' but we need a standard way to describe services (a contract). Hopefully WADL will become the standard and finally ends with this debate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good starter point is [Official Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/).

Comment: I looked at so many documents I'm ashamed that I didn't find this myself. This is the exact type of thing I was looking for to really get started - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to learn from the very beginning:

- Heavyweight Web Services (SOAP/RPC) with JAX-WS
- SOAP Contract (WSDL) and the Contract-first vs Code-First debate
- Lightweight Web Services (RestFul) with JAX-RS
- RESTFul Contract (WADL)
- Web Service Deployment (Frameworks + JAX-* deployed in some App Servers)
- Web Service Clients (i.e. usage of `wsimport`)
- Introduction to Web Service Security, Addressing, etc

I recommend you [Java Web Services. Up and Running by Martin Kalin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652112X). After that, if you need to go further with one of these subjects, I suggest you to get any of the 'cookbooks' published by O'Reilly.